# Breaking parent function of jQuery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a $.each jQuery function sitting in a parent javascript function, how do I break the parent function upon a certain index (i)?

Comment: What do you mean by "break the parent function"? Do you mean "return the parent function"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the sound of it, you have something like this:

```
function outer(someParam) {
    $.each(someParam, function(i) {
        // do something with each value in someParam
    });
}
```

You want to return from `outer` when the inner loop reaches a certain value.  You can't do this in one go.  The key point is that doing `return false` from the `$.each` callback ends the "loop".  You can then set a variable to return conditionally if you need that:

```
function outer(someParam) {
    var returnNow = false;
    $.each(someParam, function(i) {
        if (i === 5) {
            returnNow = true;
            return false;
        }

        // do something with each value in someParam
    });

    if (returnNow) {
        return;
        // return immediately
    }

    // do some other action if you want to
}
```

Comment: is there a difference btw return and return false?

Comment: @Brandon In the `$.each` handler, you must return `false` to break the loop.  If you could give a more precise example of what you're doing, it would be easier to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 10):

To break from one loop, just return `false`:

```
$('something').each(function() {
    if (need_to_break) {
        return false; // returning false stops the loop
    }
});
```

To break from / return from multiple `each` loops at once, just throw an exception:

```
var $break = {};
$('something').each(function() {
    try {
        $('something').each(function() {
            $('something').each(function() {
                $('something').each(function() {
                    throw $break;
                });
            });
        });
    } catch(E) {
        if (E != $break) throw E;
    }
});
```

And catch it in the loop you want to return to.

This is how Prototype.js [implements `break`](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/5e5cfff7c2c253eaf415c279f9083b4650cd4506/src/prototype/lang/enumerable.js#L109), in their [`Enumerable.each()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each), for instance.

A more conventional solution:

```
var do_break = false;
$('something').each(function() {
    $('something').each(function() {
        $('something').each(function() {
            $('something').each(function() {
                do_break = true;
                return false;
            });
            if (do_break) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (do_break) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (do_break) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: OP didn't mention "multiple" each loops.

Comment: I personally think using a try catch is not the right approach, just like in server side. It is meant to be used for unexpected errors, all other should be handled. See my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: This catches only break exceptions, so this is perfectly safe in this regard. Yes that's unconventional. But that's actually a very efficient way of doing this; if you try to do this in an other manner (with more than one nested loop) you will see that 1. you are doing exactly what throw/catch would have done and 2. this is harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is setting a variable(switch) on the parent function, in the each function, if i==x, break out of the each function first after changing the switch... then check for the switch value to determine whether to break out of the parent function.

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like:

```
function foo() {

var success = true;

$('element').each(function() {

    if (condition) {
        success = false;
        return success;
    }

});

if (!success)
   return false;

//should not get here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Labeled Break

```js
outerloop:
for (;;) 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        break; /* breaks inner loop */
    } 
    for (;;) 
    {
        break outerloop; /* breaks outer loop */
    }
}
```